# linux + run script on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, rsync, remote

Is it possible to run script on remote machine VIA rsync command?

- I don't want to run it VIA ssh

If not from rsync then what are the other options to run script but not from ssh?

Comment: rsync copies files, it does not execute commands (and it usually uses ssh underneath). ssh executes commands, so I don't understan why you don't want to use ssh.

Comment: There are a number of ways of setting up an environment to allow you to execute a script remotely without using `ssh`. First, you need to explain what you are trying to achieve, because `ssh` is the "obvious" solution to the requirement "run a script on a remote machine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` is used exclusively to copy files.  `rsync` uses the SSH protocol.

The correct way to execute a command on a remote machine that is running an SSH daemon (and thus may be used with `rsync` to copy files to or form), is to use `ssh`:

```
$ ssh remoteuser@remoteaddress command arguments
```

or

```
$ ssh -l remoteuser remoteaddress command arguments
```

---

In fact, this is actually what happens if you run

```
$ rsync file remoteuser@remoteaddress:
```

The `rsync` client will execute the following command on your local machine:

```
ssh -l remoteuser remoteaddress rsync --server (other arguments)
```

and then proceed to communicate with the started `rsync` server process on the other side.

You can see this by executing `rsync` with one or several `-v` flags on the command line.

Comment: how to use the last synrax - for example -  ssh -l root 10.23.1.23 rsync --server ls /etc ( this isnt works )

Comment: @yael _You_ are not supposed to run `rsync --server`. The `--server` option is exclusively used internally by `rsync`. If you want to run `ls /etc` on a remote machine, just do `ssh user@machine ls /etc`.